# orientdb migrating existing data to clusters

Tags: orientdb, nosql

I have a orient database with existing data.

But with the growth of the number of records in the db my queries are getting slow every day.

I'm planning to cluster the classes with higher number of records.

My plan is to cluster them according to the organization those records belongs.

I want to know what is the best way to cluster the existing data according to the organization field.

Comment: NoSQL databases fail often in scalability, in my experience. Have you benchmarked a classic SQL database like PostgreSQL as alternative? They can be surprisingly well optimized.

Comment: Basically I have three classes with very high number of records and those records belongs to few different organizations. So I can isolate records according to those organizations

Answer (score 0):

In orientdb there's a command move vertex which can be used to migrate an existing record to a different cluster.

MOVE VERTEX (SELECT FROM Person WHERE type = 'Customer') TO CLASS:Customer

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Move-Vertex.html

This command can reassign the edges also but if you have links towards your moving record those will be broken.